# How to wait when data-main is loaded with Require.JS before executing script?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm having the following code:

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/example1.js"></script>
```

Inside `example1` I'm doing a require for some components of which the path is supposed to be set in `scripts/main`. However, the path is not correctly set (judging by the console feedback) which leads me to believe that require.js hasn't finished loading files referenced in `scripts/main`.

This all is pretty logical (async and all that), but I'd like to know how to run code inside `example1.js` after all this is set-up.

Normally, one would simply add the app-init code to `scripts/main` probably and be done with it, but I'm building up some examples, which all share the same `scripts/main` file (which is pretty big) and I don't want to duplicate that effort.

So how to do this?

Comment: Here is a nice related discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/requirejs/O92x6EwH_rc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up doing the following, which isn't ideal (sets a global), but it's ok for my examples.

```
 <!-- sets window.requireconfig with an json object defining paths, etc.-->
 <script src="scripts/requireconfig.js"></script> 

 <!-- in top of example1.js do : require.config(window.requireconfig); -->
 <script data-main="scripts/example1" src="components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```